# MySQL Union Select with DIfferent Columns Issue

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have searched this issue high and low, and I felt certain that my query is valid.  However, I continually get an error.  Please help!

I have two tables.  One first one is for residential properties.  It has 4 columns that the second table doesn't have...  I have used NULL AS '...' for each of the missing columns.

```
SELECT `L_ListingID`, `LA1_AgentID`, `L_Class`, `L_Class_`, `L_Address`, `L_City`, `L_State`, `L_Zip`, `L_AskingPrice`, `L_InputDate`, `L_Status`, `LM_Int1_1`, `LM_Int4_12`, `LM_Char10_12`, `LM_Char10_13`, `LM_Char10_14`, `LM_Char10_15` 
FROM `properties_residential` 
WHERE 1 AND ( LCASE(TRIM(`L_Address`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_City`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Area`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_State`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Zip`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_12`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_13`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_14`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_15`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR CONCAT ( L_City, ', ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' OR CONCAT ( L_City, ' ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' ) 
UNION 
SELECT `L_ListingID`, `LA1_AgentID`, `L_Class`, `L_Class_`, `L_Address`, `L_City`, `L_State`, `L_Zip`, `L_AskingPrice`, `L_InputDate`, `L_Status`, NULL AS `LM_Int1_1`, NULL AS `LM_Int4_12`, NULL AS `LM_Char10_12`, NULL AS `LM_Char10_13`, NULL AS `LM_Char10_14`, NULL AS `LM_Char10_15` 
FROM `properties_commercial` 
WHERE 1 AND ( LCASE(TRIM(`L_Address`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_City`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Area`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_State`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Zip`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_12`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_13`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_14`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_15`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR CONCAT ( L_City, ', ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' OR CONCAT ( L_City, ' ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' ) 
ORDER BY `L_InputDate` 
DESC LIMIT 6
```

And the error is...

## 1054 - Unknown column 'LM_Char10_12' in 'where clause'

Someone please, point me in the right direction.  I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You could reduce all that to a much simpler query for demo purposes.

Comment: You can't use the alias of the column in the WHERE clause. In your case you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are using column alias in WHERE clause which is illegal in MYSQL.

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For
>   example, the following query is illegal:

```
> SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name   WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY id;
```

Above is taken from MYSQL documentation:
[MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Correction in your query:

```
SELECT `L_ListingID`, `LA1_AgentID`, `L_Class`, `L_Class_`, `L_Address`, `L_City`, `L_State`, `L_Zip`, `L_AskingPrice`, `L_InputDate`, `L_Status`, `LM_Int1_1`, `LM_Int4_12`, `LM_Char10_12`, `LM_Char10_13`, `LM_Char10_14`, `LM_Char10_15` 
FROM `properties_residential` 
WHERE 1 AND ( LCASE(TRIM(`L_Address`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_City`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Area`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_State`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Zip`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_12`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_13`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_14`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_15`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' OR CONCAT ( L_City, ', ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' OR CONCAT ( L_City, ' ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' ) 
UNION 
SELECT `L_ListingID`
, `LA1_AgentID`
, `L_Class`
, `L_Class_`
, `L_Address`
, `L_City`
, `L_State`
, `L_Zip`
, `L_AskingPrice`
, `L_InputDate`
, `L_Status`
, NULL AS `LM_Int1_1`
, NULL AS `LM_Int4_12`
, NULL AS `LM_Char10_12`
, NULL AS `LM_Char10_13`
, NULL AS `LM_Char10_14`
, NULL AS `LM_Char10_15` 
FROM `properties_commercial` 
WHERE 1 AND 
( 
LCASE(TRIM(`L_Address`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_City`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Area`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_State`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
OR LCASE(TRIM(`L_Zip`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
--OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_12`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
--OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_13`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
--OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_14`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
--OR LCASE(TRIM(`LM_Char10_15`)) LIKE '%kokomo, in' 
OR CONCAT ( L_City, ', ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' 
OR CONCAT ( L_City, ' ', L_State ) LIKE '%kokomo, in%' ) 
ORDER BY `L_InputDate` 
DESC LIMIT 6
```

In above query, The commented part is not required since the columns are itself NULL.
So you can remove commented part from WHERE clause to make your query correct.